# Lollipop without Legend and Both Axis Labels Using R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a `Lollipop chart` for a particular `r` package sticker that I am growing. I want it such that no `legend`, no `x-axis`, no `y-axis` all I want is just a plain plot.

**What I have**

```
df1 <- read.table(text =
                    "nbb_RMSE  9 0.2402482
                    mbb_RMSE  9 0.1023012
                    cbb_RMSE  8 0.2031448
                    tmbb_RMSE 4 0.2654746
                    tcbb_RMSE 9 0.4048711")

colnames(df1) <- c("Methods", "lb", "RMSE")

df1 |>
  dplyr::mutate(colour = fct_reorder(Methods, RMSE)) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(Methods, RMSE, colour = colour)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(size = 4) + 
  ggplot2::geom_segment(aes(Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", 
                            "orange", "red"),
                 labels = c(9, 8, 9, 9, 4), name = "lb") + 
  ggplot2::theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

Here is [image: its output]

**What I Want**

I want

[image: something like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `element_blank()` for the elements that you don't want in `theme`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)

df1 <- read.table(text =
                    "nbb_RMSE  9 0.2402482
                    mbb_RMSE  9 0.1023012
                    cbb_RMSE  8 0.2031448
                    tmbb_RMSE 4 0.2654746
                    tcbb_RMSE 9 0.4048711")

colnames(df1) <- c("Methods", "lb", "RMSE")

df1 |>
  dplyr::mutate(colour = fct_reorder(Methods, RMSE)) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(Methods, RMSE, colour = colour)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(size = 4) + 
  ggplot2::geom_segment(aes(Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", 
                                         "orange", "red"),
                              labels = c(9, 8, 9, 9, 4), name = "lb") + 
  ggplot2::theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>